# Nginx location and root

Tags: nginx, root, http-status-code-403

I think I have a trivial problem with nginx but I can't see it.

I have the following file tree:

```
/data/www
> main/
>> html/
>>>...some files (A)

> wiki/
>>...some files (B)
```

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  troll;

    root /data/www/main/html;

    location = / {
        index index.php;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /data/www/main/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /wiki/ {
        root /data/www/wiki;
        rewrite ^/wiki(.*)$ $1 break;
    }

    location ~ ^/wiki/(.*)\.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /data/www/wiki/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

So, I expect to open files (A) on / urls and (B) files on /wiki urls.

But I have a 403 error on /wiki:

```
2013/02/12 23:25:06 [error] 30567#0: *58 directory index of "/data/www/wiki/" is forbidden, client: ..., server: ..., request: "GET /wiki/ HTTP/1.1", host: "..."
```

Even if they have the same rights:

```
drwxrwx--- 18 apache apache 4096 févr. 10 10:35 /data/www/main/html
drwxrwx---  8 apache apache 4096 déc. 10  2010 /data/www/wiki
```

and

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 6366 févr.  8 15:10 /data/www/ifaedi/html/index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  185 déc. 10  2010 /data/www/wiki/index.php
```

If you have any idea...

Edit:

I tried the following configuration:

```
location /wiki/ {
    root /data/www;
    index index.php;
}

location ~ ^/wiki/(.*)\.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /data/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

I have no longer a 403 but php-fpm gives me a "File not found."

> 2013/02/13 13:06:55 [error] 3876#0: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: ..., server: ..., request: "GET /wiki/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "..."

Answer (score 1):

Nginx is finding the directory, but not finding an index file and isn't configured to generate directory listings, and so returns an error. You probably want to use [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) to point to your `index.php`:

```
location /wiki {
    ..
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: It changes nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a `directory index` listing problem rather than a permissions issue. Have you tried accessing a file directly instead of the root folder? The error makes sense because your wiki doesn't have an `index` directive to say which file to load as the index file. If you wanted the path to list all the files you would use the `autoindex` directive. See http://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/ for a good example.

Comment: @mgorven beat me to it and has a much more elegant example.